# Definition of a set $HK$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory

I know the definition of a coset $aH$, for some $a\in G$, where $G$ is a group. But what is $HK$, for some sets $H$ and $K$? Is it the set of all cosets $Hk$ (for $k\in K$)?

Comment: It is the *union* of all cosets $kH$ for $k \in K$.

Comment: Equivalently, it is $\{hk : h \in H, k \in K\}$. (Wouldn't it be the union of *right* cosets?)

Comment: It's worth noting in case you are not already aware, $HK$ generally need not be a subgroup. A sufficient (but not necessary) condition for $HK$ to be a subgroup is if one (or both) of $H$ and $K$ is normal in $G$. If $H$ and $K$ are finite subgroups, then whether or not $HK$ is a subgroup, we have $|HK| = |H||K|/|H \cap K|$. Also, $HK$ is a subgroup if and only if $HK = KH$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
HK = \{hk : h \in H, k \in K\}
$$